# Enabling off workspace window positioning under GNOME/Compiz

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz, window-manager

Is there any option available for enabling window positioning into an off viewable area under Compiz on GNOME? By default, any window that's to be positioned off workspace will be forced to fit into the viewable area.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @DoR Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Why do you want a window off of the viewable area? Would it work to have the window start up already minimized?

Comment: @DoR Well, not totally off, but 'partially'.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but if you have your workspaces set up in a horizontal row, you can set up hotkeys to shift a window to above/below workspace, you can shift a window to the top or bottom of the "cube". It is then "offscreen" and not visible in any of the four workspaces.

(For example, I have mine set to Super+Shift+Arrow to shift a window to another workspace without "following".)

Comment: That'll work, but with wasteful memory space

Answer (score 2):

Try using the window rules plugin in compiz. If you do not have this plugin you may need to ensure you compile the unsupported plugins as well.